# Multiple RewriteRule failed in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use URL Rewriting for my website, which can have following URIs:

```
- http://localhost:8888/category.php?c=31&ctitle=entreprise
- http://localhost:8888/subcategory.php?s=96&title=service
```

For the first one I use

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /category.php?c=$1&ctitle=$2 [L]
```

And the second one is

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /subcategory.php?s=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Each rewrite rules is correct, but the second one is not applied.
If I use only the second rules, it works.

This is my full htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

### REWRITE URLS
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /category.php?c=$1&ctitle=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /subcategory.php?s=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Any idea? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two pattern is same, so the first rule is applied.
Change the second pattern something different and then it will be applied too.

Comment: I change `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /subcategory.php?s=$1&title=$2 [L]` with  `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)\.html$ /subcategory.php?s=$1&title=$2 [L]` and it works now! thx